# collecting information with NumPy

Tags: python, numpy

Unable to solve the problem. My answer is not correct. Help me to understand
Task:function that takes a NumPy array and returns its shape, dimensions, and size, collected in a string

```
import numpy as np


def collect_info(array):
    shape = (2, 2, 3)
    dimensions = 3
    size = 12
    return f'Shape: {shape}; dimensions: {dimensions}; size: {size}'

collect_info()
```

Comment: You aren't looking at the array at all.  You're just hard-coding some numbers.  Try creating an array like `sample = np.zeros(3,4,5)`, then pass that to your function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

def collect_info(array):
    shape = array.shape
    dimensions = array.ndim
    size = array.size
    return f'Shape: {shape}; dimensions: {dimensions}; size: {size}'
my_array = np.array([[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[5, 6], [7, 8]]])
result = collect_info(my_array)
print(result)
```